# Symfony2 form entity add other options

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony, entity

I have an entity field, with basic settings, (class and property), and i'd like to add another option like "value not in list", so if is selected, i can trigger something in javascript.

```
->add('patrol', 'entity', array(

                'class'         => 'InterneStructureBundle:Patrol',
                'property'      => 'name',
                'empty_value'   => 'Choose',
            ))
```

I didnt find anything appart from "empty_value" which doesnt suits me because you cant trigger anything from it, and choices doesnt seems to work with entity..

Are there any ways to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `required => false` if you want to see empty value:

```
->add('patrol', 'entity', array(
            'class'         => 'InterneStructureBundle:Patrol',
            'property'      => 'name',
            'required'      => FALSE,
            'empty_value'   => 'Choose',
        ))
```

Comment: yes, i can show an empty value, but i want a value other than the ones from the entity, a value that if selected, can trigger javascript event. So it has to be a value i add myself, but i cant seem to find a way

Comment: I think you don't need to use `entity` type, try to learn more about [Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)